# How do I set up Windows 8 so that I have normal scroll direction for mouse and inverse scroll for touchpad?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, boot-camp, touchpad, scrolling

I am using Windows 8.1 on a MBP via Bootcamp.

I would like to know how I can have natural scrolling for the touchpad, but normal scrolling for the mouse.

This is how I have it set up in OS X (using Scroll Reverser), and I want to keep things consistent between OSs.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-reverse-scroll-in-windows-like-os-x-lion/) maybe?

Comment: That obviously changes the direction for both mouse and touchpad. I want it so that mouse scrolls one direction and the touchpad scrolls in another.

Comment: I don't know if that can be done unless you have your touchpad specific drivers installed